# Use an offset when you goto sections from a fixed header works different in each browser

Tags: css

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Yaz/) I have a fixed header with links to different sections of the page.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 245, 255, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.goto {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I want to give an offset when I click to a link in order the header not to cover the beginning of the section. That's why I give this top padding to the anchors.

The problem is that this works fine on Firefox and IE11 but not on Chrome and Opera.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying padding to an `inline` element (`a`). If you make your `a`'s `block` your padding will work:

```
.goto {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Yaz/2/)

Comment: Perfect, works fine now, but I can say I cannot understand why is this happening.

Comment: Because inline elements will ignore top and bottom padding.